# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'Column_name` Exception in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read the data from Hive table and then adding addition column with null value.By using this i am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`address_1`' given input columns: [postalcode, first_name, organization_name, application_number, type, last_name, country];;
```

Actually **address_1** is not the column from Hive, trying add this column with default value "**null**".

what i tried so far is:

```
val ipa_agent = hiveContext.sql("select * from agent")

val df1 = ipa_agent.withColumn("address_1",lit("null"))
```

Is there any other way to add column other than **withColumn**?

Answer (score 0):

list all columns in the query + additional one:

```
val ipa_agent = hiveContext.sql("select postalcode, first_name, organization_name, application_number, type, last_name, country, cast(null as string) as address_1 from agent")
```

Answer (score 0):

I try adding a new column using withColumn and it works fine for me

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Array(("101",1),("102",2))).toDF("id","rank")

val df_added_column = df.withColumn("address1", lit("null"));
df_added_column.show

    +---+----+--------+
    | id|rank|address1|
    +---+----+--------+
    |101|   1|    null|
    |102|   2|    null|
    +---+----+--------+
```

Other option, you can try as mentioned by leftjoin is mentioning all the columns name and adding address1 as null at the end.